# uncaught reference error $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the following error and no javascript is working on my site:
uncaught reference error $ is not defined

It was working but i cannot now see where there is something wrong Can anyone please help?

I am linking to javascript files here:

```
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jsfunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And here is the js functions script

```
//-------------------------- MENU MOVE
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".one").hover(function() {
       $(this).stop().animate({ marginTop: "5px" }, 200);

    },function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, 300);

    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".two").hover(function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({ marginTop: "5px" }, 200);

    },function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, 300);

    });
});


$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".three").hover(function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({ marginTop: "5px" }, 200);

    },function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, 300);

    });
});


$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".four").hover(function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({ marginTop: "5px" }, 200);

    },function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, 300);

    });
});


$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".five").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ marginTop: "5px" }, 200);

    },function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, 300);

    });
});


$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".plane").stop().animate({ marginRight: "2000px" }, 40000);


});


$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".signinbutton").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.5);

    },function(){
        $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 1.0);

    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".forgotton").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.5);

    },function(){
        $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 1.0);

    });
});


//-------------------------------- SOCIAL FADES
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".twitter").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.7);

    },function(){
        $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 1.0);

    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".facebook").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.7);

    },function(){
        $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 1.0);

    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".rss").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.7);

    },function(){
        $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 1.0);

    });
});

//------------------------------------ EMAIL DETAILS


$(function() {

$(".submit").click(function() {

var name = $("#name").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
    var comment = $("#comment").val();
    var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&comment=' + comment;

    if(name=='' || email=='' || comment=='')
     {
    alert('Please Give Valid Details');
     }
    else
    {
    $("#flash").show();
    $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="../img/-loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;<span class="loading">Loading Comment...</span>');
$({
        type: "POST",
  url: "comment.php",
   data: dataString,
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){

  $("ol#update").append(html);
  $("ol#update li:last").fadeIn("slow");
  document.getElementById('email').value='';
   document.getElementById('name').value='';
    document.getElementById('comment').value='';
    $("#name").focus();

  $("#flash").hide();

  }
 });
}
return false;
    });



});

// ----------------------------- Profile Email Check
$(document).ready(function() {

        //the min chars for username
        var min_chars = 3;

        //result texts
        var characters_error = 'Minimum amount of chars is 3';
        var checking_html = 'Checking...';

        //when button is clicked
        $('#check_username_availability').click(function(){
            //run the character number check
            if($('#username').val().length < min_chars){
                //if it's bellow the minimum show characters_error text '
                $('#username_availability_result').html(characters_error);
            }else{
                //else show the cheking_text and run the function to check
                $('#username_availability_result').html(checking_html);
                check_availability();
            }
        });

  });

//function to check username availability
function check_availability(){

        //get the username
        var username = $('#username').val();

        //use  to run the check
        $.post("lib/-checkemail.php", { username: username },
            function(result){
                //if the result is 1
                if(result == 1){
                    //show that the username is available
                    $('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' is not registered. They will be sent an email to invite them to sign up.');
                }else{
                    //show that the username is NOT available
                    $('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' is already registered. They will be notified of their invitation via email.');
                }
        });

}

function showImage(){
        document.getElementById('overlay').style.visibility='visible';
    }
document.getElementById('.videofullme').style['-webkit-transform'] = 'rotate(90deg)';
document.getElementById('.videofullme').style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(90deg)';
document.getElementById('.videofullme').style.WebkitTransform = 'rotate(90deg)';
```

Comment: Example page? Also change your first selector to: `$(".one, .two, .three")` and then delete the other two `$(document).read()` functions please.

Answer (score 6):

Your reference to `jquery.js` isn't loading.

Use Firebug to find out why.

Comment: +1 Beat me to the answer $ is the shorthand defined by JQuery, if Jquery isn't loading $ would definately not be defined

Answer (score 4):

Look into firebug or dev console to find out if your jQuery is loading - maybe your app server changes url, or you are referring to this JS from sub page (try changing URLs to **root-relative**, i.e. starting with `/`).

Also, in firebug you should be able to post a line on which error occurs - maybe there is another problem.

And...

```
$({                       //    <-- Shouldn't this be $.ajax ?
    type: "POST",
    url: "comment.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
        //...
```

**Edit**

Is there any posibility, that in your `jquery.js` or `jsfunctions.js` is called `jQuery.noConflict()` ? Hope not :P To avoid this, you can use `jQuery(function($){ /* ... */ });` or `(function($){ /* ... */ }(jQuery))`. Of course, assuming you have problems ONLY with `$`, not `jQuery` ;]

Comment: `try changing URLs to absolute - starting with /` URLs starting with `/` are also called relative. They are relative to the domain. Other than that +1

Comment: Yeah, my bad for misleading :/

Answer (score 0):

May be you have some other javascript library loaded with jquery like prototype try using jquery.noconflict and also use ready function once.

Comment: A conflict won't cause `$` to be undefined; it'll just amke `$` do something else.