# Javascript Uncaught Reference Error Anonymous Function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

-I run a javascript file and jquery in a .php file. But anytime it runs I get the following error.

[image]

this is the javascript code : scroll.js

```js
function setTableBody() {
  $(".table-body").height(
    $(".inner-container").height() - $(".table-header").height());
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var marginLeft = $(".outer-container").position().left; //Create var and calculate the difference from left
  setTableBody();
  $(window).resize(setTableBody);
  $(".table-body").scroll(function() {
    $(".table-header").offset({
      left: marginLeft - this.scrollLeft //minus the difference while table header scroll with table body
    });
  });
});
```

This is the code from the header php file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script language="javascript" type='text/javascript' src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type='text/javascript' src='scroll.js'></script>

</head>
<body>

<header> 
<a href="/datacentre/admin/index.php" title="Return to the homepage" id="logo">
  <img src="/datacentre/images/cagd_logo.jpg" alt="CAGD logo" 
  style="width:30px;height:30px;"/>
</a>
<span class="headerspan">CAGD Data Centre</span>

<a href="/datacentre/webhelp/index.htm" title="Return to the homepage" id="helpfile">
  help
</a>

</header>
  
 <div class="nav-div" id="nav-div">   
 <nav>
<ul id="nav-ul">
        <li><a href="/datacentre/admin/index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/datacentre/admin/register.php">Booking</a></li> 
        <li><a href="">Activities <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <div id=drop-down-div>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="/datacentre/admin/request_pending.php">Waiting Approval</a></li>
     <li><a href="/datacentre/admin/approved_list.php">Approved</a></li>
     <li><a href="/datacentre/admin/running_tasks.php">Work in process</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/datacentre/admin/completed_list.php">Completed</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
       </li> 
       <li><a href="">Manage User<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <div id=drop-down-div>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="/datacentre/admin/create_user.php">Create User</a></li>
     <li><a href="/datacentre/admin/delete_user.php">Delete User</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
        </li>

        <li><a href="">Manage System<span class="caret"></span></a>
               <div id=drop-down-div>
    <ul>
          <li><a href="/datacentre/admin/activity_type.php">Request Table</a></li>
                                       <li><a href="/datacentre/admin/update_event.php">Update Event</a></li>
                                       <li><a href="/datacentre/admin/delete_event.php">Delete Event</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
        </li>

        <li><a href="">Report<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <div id=drop-down-div>
    <ul>
                <li><a href="/datacentre/admin/detail_report.php">Main</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="">Sort By<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                           <div id=drop-down-div>
                                             <ul>
     <li><a href="/datacentre/admin/report_sort_by_name.php">Name</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Purpse</a></li>
                                          </ul>
                                       </div>
    </ul>
   </div>
        </li>

      <form id="search-form" method="post" action="search.php">
  <input name="searcher" id="search-bar" type="text" placeholder="Type to Search">
  <input id="search-button" type="submit" value="Find">
</form>
    
   </ul>

    </nav>
</div>
```

This is the main php file

```html
<?PHP

session_start();

if (!(isset($_SESSION['login_user']) && $_SESSION['login_user'] != '')) {

header ("Location: loginForm.php");

}

?>


<?php
include('/templates/header.php');
$host = "localhost"; // Host name 
$username = "root"; // Mysql username 
$password = ""; // Mysql password 
$db_name = "datacentre"; // Database name 
$tbl_name = "data_centre_users"; // Table name 
$server_name = "localhost";

// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($server_name, $username, $password, $db_name, 3306);
if($con->connect_error){
   die("Connection failed: ".$con->connect_error);
}

// Check connection
if($con->connect_error){
 die("Connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ";
$result = $con->query($sql);


function myDate($x){
         
   if ( !strtotime($x)) {
  return "00-00-0000 00:00:00";
   }
    else{
  return strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S',
               strtotime($x));
     }
  return "";
}         


?>

  <section id="content">

  <div class="outer-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div class="table-header">
        <table id="headertable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="center"><strong>ID</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>FirstName</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Lastname</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Department</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Unit</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Request</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Purpose</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Description</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Booking Time</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Access Time</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Exit Time</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Status</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Approved / Denied By</strong></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
               
      <div class="table-body">
        <table id="bodytable">
         <?php
           if($result->num_rows > 0){
                // output data of each row
                while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
             <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['first_name']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['last_name']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['department']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['unit']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['request']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['purpose']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['description']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center" >
                           <input name="booking_time" type="datetime-local" id="booking_time" value="<?php echo myDate($rows                               ['booking_time']); ?>" size="15">
                         </td>
                        <td class="center">
                         <input name="access_time" type="datetime-local" id="access_time" value="<?php echo myDate($rows                         ['access_time']); ?>" size="15">
                        </td>
                        <td class="center">
                         <input name="exit_time" type="datetime-local" id="exit_time" value="<?php echo myDate($rows['exit_time']); 
                        ?>" size="15" </td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['status']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['approved_by']; ?></td>         
            </tr>
           
          </tbody>
       
       <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
       </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </section>

<?php
$con->close();

function concantName($first , $second){

  return $first."  ".$second;

}

?>

</body>

</html>
```

This is the CSS code

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.outer-container {
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10em;
    left: 10em;
    right: 200em;
    bottom: 40em;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
}
.inner-container {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.table-header {
    position: relative;
}
.table-body {
    overflow: auto;
}
.header-cell {
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: left;
    height: 40px;
}
.body-cell {
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: left;
}
.col1, .col3, .col4, .col5 {
    width: 120px;
    min-width: 120px;
}
.col2 {
    min-width: 300px;
}
```

Any suggestion for a solution

Comment: Your jQuery file is not found. Look closer into the console.

Comment: Obviously there is no such file in such directory: `/datacentre/admin/jquery-1.11.3.min.js`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [uncaught reference error $ is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215065/uncaught-reference-error-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console is telling you the problem. You have an error when the browser is trying to reach `http://localhost/datacentre/admin/jquery-1.11.3.min.js`

The file name is wrong or maybe not here at all.

Comment: thanks  , guess have to learn to interprate error messages from console.